# Matching Multiline Matching pattern in xml

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

How do I match following pattern:

```
<aaa class = "dog">
   <bbb id = "one"/>
</aaa>
<aaa class = "dog">
   <bbb id = "two"/>
</aaa>
<aaa class = "dog">
   <bbb id = "three"/>
</aaa>
```

I want:

```
<aaa class = "dog">
   <bbb id = "three"/>
</aaa>
```

I use:

```
^(.)*dog(.|\r|\n|\t)*(three)
```

but it matches:

```
<aaa class = "dog">
   <bbb id = "one"/>
</aaa>
<aaa class = "dog">
   <bbb id = "two"/>
</aaa>
<aaa class = "dog">
   <bbb id = "three
```

How should i edited the regex to match what i want?

Comment: As your regex is ending with (three), it definitely would match till "three".
Do you want to match the exact text?

Comment: actually i want it to match three lines stated in "I want:"

Comment: Is `<aaa>` and `<bbb>` "static"? E.g. can you use `^<aaa\s+class\s*\=\s*"dog">`?

Comment: What i want is the whole three lines:

    <aaa class = "dog">
       <bbb id = "three"/>
    </aaa>

Answer (score 1):

if you want to match the exact three lines mentioned, you could use the following regex:

```
<aaa class = "dog">[\r\n\t\s]*<bbb id = "three"/>[\r\n\t\s]*</aaa>
```